# Sum two variables by two specific columns and compute quotient

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1`:

```
    Plant name      Brand       Region  Units produced  capacity  Cost incurred
    Gujarat Plant   Hyundai     Asia    8500            9250      18500000
    Haryana Plant   Honda       Asia    10000           10750     21500000
    Chennai Plant   Hyundai     Asia    12000           12750     25500000
    Zurich Plant    Volkswagen  Europe  25000           25750     77250000
    Chennai Plant   Suzuki      Asia    6000            6750      13500000
    Rengensburg     BMW         Europe  12500           13250     92750000
    Dingolfing      Mercedes    Europe  14000           14750     103250000
```

I want a output dataframe with the following format:

```
df2=    Region      BMW   Mercedes  Volkswagen  Toyota  Suzuki  Honda   Hyundai                             
        Europe
        North America
        Asia
        Oceania
```

where the contents of each cell equals `sum(cost incurred) / sum(units produced)` for that specific `Region` and `Brand`.

Code I have tried, resulting in a ValueError:

```
for i,j in itertools.zip_longest(range(len(df2),range(len(df2.columns)):
    if (df2.index[i] in list(df1["Region"]) & df2.columns[j] in list(df1["Brand"])==True:
        temp1 = df1["Region"]==df2.index[i]
        temp2 = df1["Brand"]==df2.columns[j]] 
        df2.loc[df2.index[i],df2.columns[j]] = df1(temp1&temp2)["Cost incurred"].sum()/
                                            df1(temp1&temp2)["Units Produced"].sum()
    elif (df2.index[i] in list(df1["Region"]) & df2.columns[j] in list(df1["Brand"])==False:
        df2.loc[df2.index[i],df2.columns[j]] = 0
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
> ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 0):

[df.pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) is designed for pivot-and-aggregation capability. A quick(?) and dirty solution:

```
df1.pivot_table(index="Region", columns="Brand", values="Cost incurred", aggfunc=np.sum)\
/ df1.pivot_table(index="Region", columns="Brand", values="Units produced", aggfunc=np.sum)
```

**Output**

```
Brand      BMW   Honda      Hyundai  Mercedes  Suzuki  Volkswagen
Region                                                           
Asia       NaN  2150.0  2146.341463       NaN  2250.0         NaN
Europe  7420.0     NaN          NaN    7375.0     NaN      3090.0
```